# What's the difference between True and False in python grammar?

Tags: python

I'm reading [the python language specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) and found there's a `None`,
`True`, and `False` token. I can understand the difference between `None` and
`False` since `None` is not a boolan. But, about `True` and `False`, why not
just `BOOLEAN` there? Is there any case where `True` and `False`
behave differently? Or is there any semantical difference?

Note that I'm asking about the difference in grammar not the boolean value which
is obviously different.

Comment: All the 21st century is based on the difference between True and False.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `True` and `False` are distinct tokens, so they're both in the grammar. Are you asking why there isn't a `boolean: 'True' | 'False'` production?

Comment: `True` and `False` are Python constants, therefore considered an `atom`. Not sure what else you are looking for

Comment: `boolean: ('True' | 'False')`, would just add another indirection. Why is that *better* in your interpretation?

Comment: So there no difference then? I'm writing a python interpreter now for learning purpose. That's why I need to now if there's any difference.

Comment: Are you something that isn't answered by [the grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)?

Comment: I'm asking if there is any difference in behavior as an object or as a boolean value. Or it's just an exact opposite (which is mean those two are equal in term of boolean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a formalization of the fact that `True` and `False` are special names in python3: you can't assign to them.

The reason that they aren't BOOLEAN is simply that boolean isn't a [valid token](https://docs.python.org/3/library/token.html) for the parser.

*Note:* You will find this detail missing in the python2 grammar, where you *can* actually assign to the names True and False (...if you want to watch the world burn).

Comment: And then you can `del` them to restore sense!

Comment: @holdenweb - And then you can try `del`ing them again, but it'll tell you that they're not defined, even though you can still use them and see that they're what they should be.

Comment: I want to watch the world burn XD

Comment: You'll need 2.7 for that, @MasBagol! @ArtOfWarfare - just goes to show you can't always believe what the interpreter tells you! Once upon a time (extra points: which release?) you could delete them from the built-in namespace, which caused even greater consternation!

Comment: To really watch the world burn, try `del __builtins__.True`.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
       '[' [testlist_comp] ']' |
       '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |
       NAME | NUMBER | STRING+ | '...' | 'None' | 'True' | 'False')
```

`NAME`, `NUMBER`, and `STRING` are tokens representing three classes of tokens. Each of them represents an unlimited set of possible tokens. There are many number literals that can be classified as `NUMBER`, many string literals that can be `STRING`s, etc.

There are only two boolean literals, `True` and `False`. The tokenizer could have been written to classify them both as `BOOLEAN`. Could have, but wasn't. They're only referred to once in the entire grammar, so writing `'True' | 'False'` is no big deal.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably from the reference to which you linked you are referring to the grammatical production

```
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
       '[' [testlist_comp] ']' |
       '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |
       NAME | NUMBER | STRING+ | '...' | 'None' | 'True' | 'False')
```

This simply gives the strings `None`, `True`, and `False` the same status as certain other language elements. While it would have been possible to create a definition of a Boolean atom which could either be `True` or `False` and use that in the grammar, what purpose would that have served?

In point of fact, even in 2.7 you can try to delete the `True` and `False` definitions from the `__builtins__` namespace:

```
>>> del __builtins__.True
>>> del __builtins__.False

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sholden/.virtualenvs/jlab/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
NameError: global name 'True' is not defined
```

Interestingly, if you delete `False` first there is no complaint about the deletion of `True` :-)

However, this makes even quite standard Python make no sense at all:

```
>>> 1 == 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sholden/.virtualenvs/jlab/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
NameError: global name 'True' is not defined
```

This underlines that Python was produced as "a programming language for consenting adults." Ultimately it gives you enough rope to hang yourself if you are determined to do that.